# What is the bundle size of svelte-materialify?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

I want to use **svelte-materialify** for my project and I wanted to know the bundle size, before I end up with large bundle size app. so if you used svelte-materialify, please tell me the build bundle size. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can answer this kind of question with a site like bundlephobia.

For svelte-materialify : https://bundlephobia.com/result?p=svelte-materialify@0.3.4

> 81.5k, gzipped.

However, this library is tree-shakable: components you don't use will not be in the final js. You should try in your project and then use a plugin like `rollup-plugin-analyser` to see the final size in your context/pages.

Answer (score 1):

to decrease size of bundles i can use only need components. but need wrapped it minimal wrapper. it wrapper having in the new release 0.3.6 (an screens show sizes of a files https://github.com/TheComputerM/svelte-materialify/issues/155).

```
<script>
    import Button from 'svelte-materialify/src/components/Button/index.js';
    import MaterialAppMin from "svelte-materialify/src/components/MaterialApp/MaterialAppMin";
    let theme = 'light';
</script>

<MaterialAppMin {theme}>
<Button class="success-color">success</Button>
      ...
</MaterialAppMin>
```

it decrease size of bundles.

but it method load more the code

```
import {Button} from 'svelte-materialify';
```

https://svelte-materialify.vercel.app/components/material-app/